# HQL error: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I am getting started with Hibernate and I am using HQL, using some joins to retrieve data from the db but getting this error, any help on how to solve this is appreciated.

Field.hbm.xml file:

```
    <id name="id" type="string">
        <column name="field_map_cd" />
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
```

Rule.hbm.xml file:

```
    <many-to-one name="src_field_map" column="field_map_cd" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <many-to-one name="tgt_field_map" column="field_map_cd" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

HQL query:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.src_field_map.id, s1.field_map_nm as src_field_map_nm, 
t.tgt_field_map.id,s2.field_map_nm as tgt_field_map_nm from Rule as t 
left join t.src_field_map as s1 left join t.tgt_field_map as s2 
with (s1.id = t.src_field_map.id and s2.id = t.tgt_field_map.id)
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR:  with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.handleWithFragment(HqlSqlWalker.java:465)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:413)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3858)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3644)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at Utilities.test.readXrefRule(test.java:67)
at Utilities.test.main(test.java:171)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced 
two different from-clause elements [select t.id, t.name, t.src_field_map.id,
s1.field_map_nm as src_field_map_nm,t.tgt_field_map.id, s2.field_map_nm
as tgt_field_map_nm, orm.entity.OS_Rule as t left join t.src_field_map
as s1 left join t.tgt_field_map as s2 with (s1.id = t.src_field_map.id 
and s2.id = t.tgt_field_map.id )]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at Utilities.test.readRule(test.java:67)
at Utilities.test.main(test.java:171)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    t.name, 
    s1.id, 
    s1.field_map_nm as src_field_map_nm, 
    s2.id,
    s2.field_map_nm as tgt_field_map_nm
from Rule as t 
left join t.src_field_map as s1 
left join t.tgt_field_map as s2
```

I think you don't need the `with` clause since you only use the FK, which is implicit anyway.

Your `with` clause is actually referencing the same table id twice:

```
s1.id = t.src_field_map.id
```

since `s1 = t.src_field_map`

So your with clause translates to:

```
t.src_field_map.id = t.src_field_map.id
```

So, you can just remove the `with` clause.

Comment: Followed your suggestion plus fixed the couple many-to-one column property value in the Rule.hbm.xml file with the correct fields and is working like a charm.