# HQL Left join with condition refering to third entity

Tags: left-join, hql

I have three entities/tables

A has a one to many relation to B and B has a one to one relation to C.

I want to get all A and left join with B that have a specific C value

e.g.

I want A with B that have C.value = 'A'

Table A

```
  id

   1

   2

   3
```

Table B

```
idToA ║ idToC ║ value

    1 ║     1 ║   'X'

    2 ║     1 ║   'Y'

    3 ║     2 ║   'Z'
```

Table C

```
  id ║  value

   1 ║    'A'

   2 ║    'B'

   3 ║    'C'
```

and have the result be

```
A.id ║ b.value

   1 ║     'X'

   2 ║     'Y'

   3 ║
```

I managed to get the following SQL:

```
select a.id, b.value 
from A left outer join B on A.id = B.idToA and B.idToC in 
  (select id from C where C.value = 'A')
```

But I can't seem to find a way to convert this query to HQL because of the subquery inside the condition for the left join.

Answer (score 0):

After reading JPA2.0 spec, the left join is defined as:

```
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN join_association_path_expression [AS] identification_variable
[join_condition]
```

Which means you could translate your SQL to JPQL (and I expect your Hibernate to be at least 4.3):

```
select a.id, b.value 
from A a
left join a.idToA b on b.idToC in  (select id from C where C.value = 'A') // or property pointing to C
```

If you encounter this error: *with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements*, then read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835442/hql-error-with-clause-referenced-two-different-from-clause-elements).

Comment: The issue with that query is that it won't return A that don't have B which are associated with C whose values are 'A'. As seen in the last part of my question, I want all A, regardless of the left join.

Comment: I edited my answer which was pretty much your SQL query translated to JPQL. The right side of the on, with the subquery, can move in the `where` part.

Comment: The 'on' and 'where' conditions do different things. The 'on' condition restricts which B are allowed to be joined, while the 'where' condition will restrict which rows will be present for the result.

If you place the condition in the where, the last row of the example result in the question won't appear.

Comment: I think my last update will close your question. I tried it on hibernate 4.3.1.Final.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not asked in a way which is conducive to clear thinking about JPA or Hibernate. The language should not be about foreign keys such as a.idToB. Instead your references should be more like

```
class A {
   @OneToMany()
   private List<B> bList;

   ... etc
}

class B {
    @ManyToOne()
    private A a;

    @OneToMany()
    private List<C> cList;

    ... etc ... 
}
```

The keys are not specified in your queries. They are mapped by your classes so that the joins can be managed by your JPA implementation. Then your example query might look more like this

```
"select a.id, b.value from A a 
    left join a.bList b
    left join b.cList c
    where c.value = :valueParam
    or b is null"
```