# grails HQL with clause

Tags: grails, hql

since my earlier question is unanswered, I want to ask one part again.

HQL

```
    from Agenda agr 
    inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
    left join agr.employer wgr
    left join wgr.contracts cnt with agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.ValidUntil
```

I got the message

```
with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
```

Native SQL

```
left join contract cnt
    on agr.wgv_id = cnt.wgv_id
       and agr.date >= cnt.validFrom
       and agr.date < cnt.validTill
```

In the previous question the suggestion was, use HQL and the 'with' clause. It this possible one way or the other? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{replaced}

you only need left join if you wish to capture null records otherwise just use join

```
from Agenda agr
    inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
    left join agr.employer wgr
    left join wgr.contracts cnt
where agr.date >= :start
    and agr.date <= :end
    and ((agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.validTill) or agr.employer is Null)
```

Wanted

```
from Agenda agr
        inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
        left join agr.employer wgr
        left join wgr.contracts cnt with agr.date >=cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.valifTill
    where agr.date >= :start
        and agr.date <= :end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Agenda agr 
    inner join agr.agenda a
     left join agr.employer wgr
    left join wgr.contracts cnt 
 where (a.employee.id = :employeeId) and (agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.datm < cnt.validTill)
```

you only need left join if you wish to capture null records otherwise just use join

As by comment:

> A employer has many contracts, but only one of them is valid depending at a given date

In which case you could do a exists clause to select 1 row to match criteria, unsure if the following is exactly correct (i.e. if cnt is needed at all above and needs that extra ) but may be of use:

```
from Agenda agr 
        inner join agr.agenda a
         left join agr.employer wgr
        left join wgr.contracts cnt 
     where (a.employee.id = :employeeId) and 
     exists (select 1 from Contracts cnt1 where cnt1.id = cnt.id  and agr.date < cnt1.valifTill and agr.date >=cnt1.validFrom)
```

This might be more on point if you don't need anything back from cnt

```
    from Agenda agr 
    inner join agr.agenda a
     left join agr.employer wgr
 where (a.employee.id = :employeeId) and 
 exists (select 1 from Contracts cnt1 where agr.date < cnt1.valifTill and agr.date >=cnt1.validFrom)
```

Another test:

Try changing the agr comparison values as a test for now to actual parameters being passed in so change agr.date >=cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.valifTill to agr.date >= :start and agr.date < :end

Does this work ?

```
from Agenda agr
        inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
        left join agr.employer wgr
        left join wgr.contracts cnt with (agr.date >= :start and agr.date < :end)
    where (agr.date >= :start
        and agr.date <= :end)
```

**Update 3 16th Sept 2015**

A few days ago this had me thinking and trying some new ways of making it work.. It was based on a totally different data set and I don't have it any more but here is what I found:

```
select new map (agr as agr, agr.date as lst)
from Agenda agr
            inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
            left join agr.employer wgr
            left join wgr.contracts cnt with (lst >=cnt.validFrom and lst < cnt.valifTill)
        where (agr.date >= :start
            and agr.date <= :end)
```

This I think threw an exception about not recognising lst. This got me thinking that whilst its within this with loop some how its not able to keep existing relations.. (possibly a bug in hibernate)

So I ended up doing :

```
select new map (agr as agr)
from Agenda agr
            inner join agr.agenda a with a.employee.id = :employeeId
            left join agr.employer wgr
            left join wgr.contracts cnt with (agr >=cnt.validFrom and agr < cnt.validTill)
        where (agr.date >= :start
            and agr.date <= :end)
```

This bizarrely worked but please note that agr which is Agenda also contained the same date fields ValidFrom and ValidTill. I did attempt another dateField that was only in one and not the other and it did not appear to work any more. 
My test did not attempt to pull any data back it was more about the hql syntax working which in the last example appeared to work.

This I hope clears up the muffled comments way down further in the comments of this answer.

Comment: Indeed, I need the null records, that is exactly the point.  What is the possible solution, the where clause is for this situation not useable. There are agenda records without employers, and those must be included, the workaround a WHERE with an extra OR on null values is not what I want. The previous post suggested that HQL including a WITH clause was the solution, but I don't get it working.

Comment: try changing that segment to  where (a.employeer.id is null or a.employee.id = :employeeId)

Comment: As said, the point is I don't want the WHERE clause solution but the JOIN WITH construction if possible. Appearantly the JOIN WITH does not work in case of mapped id and extra AND's on de date fields. A employer has many contracts, but only one of them is valid depending at a given date.

Comment: is employee another relation ? if so try  inner join agr.agenda a  join a.employee e with e.id = :employeeId

Comment: I already did that, and yes there are employees and employers. See the WANTED code. Is the Join WITH only working for parameters?

Comment: http://www.bmchild.com/2012/05/hibernate-with-clause-hql-equivalent-of.html. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html You may supply extra join conditions using the HQL with keyword.

from Cat as cat
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
        with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0

Comment: Exactly, appearantly the condition can only be "kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0"  and not "agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.validTill". In otherwords, compare with another join field. Is there a JOIN WITH solution possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I right that this is a "subquery" solution? and this costs extra, compared to the native sql left join or the HQL with (not working)?

Comment: or this might be even better than a subselect? and ((agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.validTill) or agr.employer is Null), anyway is is not the solution I want.

Comment: simplify it  Include both with clauses but only have 1 statement for each with. Does this work or does this throw back same exception ? http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/With-clause-referenced-two-different-from-clause-elements.aspx I think you may find just by having 2 different with is causing the problem.  2. I would also look at the relations and ensure the hasMany belongsTo is correctly mapped.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835442/hql-error-with-clause-referenced-two-different-from-clause-elements  & also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7321.

Comment: I removed the WITH on employee, so remaining only a WITH on contract, still give the message "with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements". And, what do you mean with "1 statement for each with"? I need >= validFrom and <validTill, so I can not reduce it to one statement.

Comment: Native SQL on agr.wgv_id = cnt.wgv_id
and agr.date >= cnt.cnt_validfrom
and agr.date < cnt.cnt_validtill

Comment: Never mind my suggestion you had reached via removing the other where and leaving the one with multiple clause causing the issue, I have yet updated my answer again, it seems the issue you are facing I think relates to the actual values you are comparing check my updated answer

Comment: The suggested code works, I álready tried it e few days ago as a test. I also said the with clause appearantly only works with literals. I need the comparison agr.date vs cnt.validFrom. when selected a week, eg monday could have a valid contract and tuesday and further an invaliden or no contract.

Comment: I can't be a 100% on this doing some tests and found (where cnt.date < agr and cnt.date >=agr) could work and I think it then matches up the date fields -  didn't do a proper test but the syntax worked so your choice is to either do the exists method as above or you could try messing with (where cnt.valifTill < agr and cnt.validFrom >= agr) and having those fields in both tables possibly with duplicate dates etc. Bearing mind hql can get confused over same naming convention so not at all sure about any of this.

Comment: I will be back after trying your suggestions, your help is very much appreciated, please continue. Unfortunately I can try it next week. Please read my results next week. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem was with the usage of the WITH clause, with the WHERE clause there is no problem. WHERE and ((agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.validTill) or agr.employer is Null) is working, but LEFT JOIN emp.contracts cnt with agr.date >= cnt.validFrom and agr.date < cnt.validTill isn't. Anyway I will try the exists suggestion.

Comment: sorry i got confused over the test was with WITH - segment should be ::: left join wgr.contracts cnt with (cnt.valifTill < agr and cnt.validFrom >= agr) but its the entire agr object so unsure if it compares to equivalent field in agr

Comment: "but its the entire agr object so unsure if it compares to equivalent field in agr ". I don't see what you mean, please explain.

Comment: did you read the 3rd update in the answer above.. ? It tries to explain this

Comment: I have added some relations and now is is possible to join contracts and make usage of the with clause. Next problem I ran into is, "how to join t3 (id, fk1, fk2) to t1.pk1 and t2.pk2? Suggestions? The relations only take part of pk1=fk1 automatically, but the pk2=fk2 part is the problem.

Comment: might be worth updating your question and highlighting what you changed to make it work, for the purpose to make it easier for others to understand in the future who hit this question. In regards to your new question it again may be worth raising a new question and highlighting actual issue, from a glimpse It might be have to a be a subquery such as using join table1 t1, table3 t3   left join t3.something sp        (using comma)

Comment: as said, the new relations solved the problem, for the new problem I will make a seperate question. Thx a lot.